# webcam photo capture on startup repost

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a webcam photo on login using Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/311569/take-a-webcam-photo-on-login-using-windows-7)

How do I set up my webcam to capture an image on the sly each time my account (or any account) logs on? Is there some specific software that will do this?

I have a VGA webcam and running Windows 7.

Comment: ohh ok, so ill delete this post?

Comment: @user913233 - Only the duplicate answers your question. If it doesn't edit this question to explain why it didn't answer your question